# Make .NET Delegates (for filtering and ordering) 'trustable'

Tags: .net, delegates, trust

What would be the best way of making Delegates used in Linq Where and OrderBy methods 'trustable'?

For instance, if my code was being passed these types `Func<T,Boolean>` and `Func<T>`, what would be the best option to check that these will only operate on the object passed to them, and not, for instance, do nasty things such as access the filesystem, etc?

I suppose one way would be to startup have a partially-trusted AppDomain, and the delegates run in that, but I wonder if there is any other option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option would be use `Expression<Func<...>>` instead of `Func<...>`, then you simply walk the tree (from `x => x.Foo` etc) and validate what objects and methods are used - but you would have to limit to **your** objects, as obviously even `.Foo` could be malign. The advantage here is that *to the caller* it looks and feels the same as passing a delegate as a lambda.

An easier way may be for them to pass you a string (name) or enum that you use for the sort / filter / etc.

Comment: And of course this only works for expression and not for statement lamdas.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - still such a shame that the compiler won't write Expression.Block in 4.0

Comment: @Marc I agree. It's a pity that they didn't improve their lamda to expression converter when they introduced these new expression types in .net 4.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - of course *technically* the expression converter has never been defined (it isn't part of the language spec), so it is pretty arbitrary what you can do :)

Comment: A downside of this approach is that it has a significant performance impact (to analyse and compile the expression)

Comment: @Thomas - it'll have an impact - whether it is *significant* depends on the scenario. And you can always compile the lambda and store it (after analysis); then it will have no overhead.